# In "The Story of Doctor Dolittle", why does the cat's meat man get sick every Christmas-time?

Tags: meaning, doctor-dolittle, hugh-lofting

In *The Story of Doctor Dolittle*, the author writes,

> But the Cat’s-meat-Man wasn’t very rich and he only got sick once a year—at Christmas-time, when he used to give the Doctor sixpence for a bottle of medicine.

Is the implication that the man gets drunk every Christmas and is given treatment for his hangover?

Comment: yes, that's the implication

Comment: Was the ‘bottle of medicine’ really a bottle of alcohol (or at least, a medicine which was [effectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydia_Pinkham#Lydia_E._Pinkham's_Vegetable_Compound) [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peruna_(patent_medicine)) [same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaica_ginger) thing), making the purchase the cause of drunkenness rather than a result of it?

Answer (score 2):

I understand this as the Cats' Meat Man giving Dr Dolittle a Christmas present, disguised as a purchase of medicine that he doesn't need.